# my cat gets stuck on the same rooftop every day

Tags: cats, behavior

we have a cat whom we raised from birth (which was 1 year ago).

For most of the day she stays at home, however sometimes she will venture outside,

there are 2 other cats and a dog with whom she is living.

As a kitten she was terrified of everything (things like her food for example).

A few weeks ago she started going up on the roof of my neighbour's house (we have not yet found a way to prevent her from doing so and we can't cut her nails because she tends to venture out of the house and doing so will put her in danger)

**the problem is she gets stuck there EVERY DAY** at which point we have to go to the neighbor's balcony and get her down.

(i don't know if this is relevant to territory or something but one of our other cats is her mother).

Any suggestions on how to prevent her from getting stuck up there (or training her to stay away from that area) are welcome.

Comment: How fast do you react, when she is stuck on the roof? Maybe she calculates to come down with your attention into the equation? Would she be at risk, if you would wait for some time (for example missing the feeding time) before getting her down again?

Comment: the first time this happened it took us a day and a half to figure out that she had gone up there, and in a few cases it happens when our neighbors are not at home, meaning it takes us a while to get her down.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you train the cat to not go on the roof?**

Not really. Indoors, where you have complete control of your space, you can redirect the cat from areas you don't want it to go to areas it's allowed to go. But outside, of course this is not possible.

**The only options I can think of are:**

1. **Physically block its access to the roof.** This solution entirely depends on whether it's even possible to block the cat from climbing the roof, and if your neighbor is nice enough to allow you to modify his home for your cat. I rather doubt that is the case.
2. **Make your cat a full time indoor cat.** This solution seems much more realistic to me. It also has the added benefit of making your cat overall *much* safer. People forget that although cats are predators, they are still also prey animals, that normally live short hazardous lives. Being inside allows them to live a long, safe, happy life. You can still give your cat experiences of the outdoors too, by building it an outdoor enclosure a.k.a. catio, or by leash training it, if it will accept that.

Comment: about option 2: we have found it a bit impractical keeping her inside, she tends to get very jumpy when she is cooped up for too long and she also tends to find an open window or some other way to get out. is there a way to entice her to stay inside?

Comment: @EdoMor does she have appropriate enrichment available indoors? You can't just drop a cat in a human house and expect her to be happy with it; they need a variety of toys, "cat trees" to climb/perch on, places to look out windows, places to nap, places to hide--and if their humans don't make those available, they'll find their own alternatives (which are generally places you don't want them to be).